# Remote execution of set-culture

Tags: powershell

[Set-Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture?view=win10-ps) sets the culture for new ps sessions persistent on local usage

```
Set-Culture -CultureInfo de-DE
```

...but does silently fail on remote execution, e.g.:

```
$secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString yourSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $ENV:COMPUTERNAME\YourUsername, $secPassword
$session = new-pssession -computername localhost -credential $cred
invoke-command -command { Set-Culture -CultureInfo de-DE } -Session $session 
invoke-command -command { get-Culture } -Session $session

LCID             Name             DisplayName                     PSComputerName
----             ----             -----------                     --------------
1033             en-US            English (United States)         machineName
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: What leads you to conclude that it failed?

Comment: There is no change after execution i can see in contrast to interaktive execution

Comment: What does `Get-Culture` return when you invoke that in the remote session (after running `Set-Culture`)?

Comment: It looks like you've run into a _bug_, as of (at least) Windows PowerShell v5.1.17134.590, which I encourage you to report in the [Windows PowerShell UserVoice forum](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell). (As of v6.2.0, PowerShell *Core* doesn't yet have a `Set-Culture` cmdlet, though its introduction is [being discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3833)).